# loop trough items, add them to a object and do console.log

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array

i am looping trough radio buttons to add their values to a javascript  object. When i am doing a console.log i am seeing only the last item as an "part of a object" not the whole object.

What am I doing wrong?

```
      var steps = {};
      var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
       for(var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        if(elements[i].type === "radio")
         {
           Object.assign(steps, {name: elements[i].value});                
         }
       }

     console.log(steps);
```

Comment: Can you please share the whole code (like including the html necessary to reproduce) or the `console.log` result of yor process? Those would make it a great question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing the following in a loop

> Object.assign(steps, {name: elements[i].value});

what this basically does is add a key *name* with value *elements[i].value*.

> The [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

You need to convert **steps** to an array and then push all of the keys in it. Alternatively you can change the *name* key and make it unique although converting it to array would be preferred.

For array you need to do something like this

```
var steps = [];
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].type === "radio") {
    steps.push({ name: elements[i].value });
  }
}

console.log(steps);
```